# Not sure how I can end the else statement here

Tags: html, if-statement, logic, nunjucks

I am trying to add some logic to a link so that I can have a toggle between states

In the HTML I am using some nunjucks to set the content for the link in the page template. This works:

```
prototypeLinks = [{href: 'thispage?from=indexpage', text: 'Reset the list of options'} if data['from'] == 'contentpage'] %}
```

But when I try to add an else if to create the toggle, it doesn't work:

```
prototypeLinks = [{href: 'thispage?from=indexpage', text: 'Reset the list of options'} if data['from'] == 'contentpage'] else { href: 'thispage?from=indexpage', text: 'Reduce the options' } endif %}
```

When I run it I get:

```
[Line 5, Column 131] expected block end in set statement
```

It feels like there is a way to add the expected block end.

Comment: Maybe you're missing an % before ```endif %}```

Comment: You need to show more code to get help from folks here.  One-liners won't cut it.